# Find all the non distinct values of a field in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

How can I list all the non-distinct values of a field in a collection in mongodb? I found distinct command to find all the distinct values for the field but I want the opposite.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can do this using [**`.aggregate()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/)

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$field",
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},
    { "$match": {
        "count": { "$gt": 1 }
    }}
])
```

Also see the [SQL to Aggregate Mapping](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/) examples.